# check if list of keywords is in a line

Tags: python

i want to check if 3 keywords are in line, the keywords being

```
( ,) and module
```

I tried

```
if "(" or ")" or "module" in line:
```

That didn't work. How do I check it?

Comment: all of them or any of them?

Comment: this is not how or works.

Comment: `if re.search(r'[()]|module', line):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change it to following :

```
if "(" in line or ")" in line or "module" in line:
```

Actually your command is equal to `if True or True or "module" in line:`

[Boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) :

> In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted as **false**:
>
> False, None, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). **All other values are interpreted as true**.

Comment: You have answered 9 seconds earlier, deleting my answer

Comment: Why not __any(kw in line for kw in ())__